# Google-Earth will not launch

Tags: 64-bit, install-from-source, google-earth

After installing Ubuntu 12.04LTS 64bit I am unable to launch Google Earth.

When I try to launch in terminal I get the following:

```
pst007x@pst007x-Serval-Professional:~$ cd /opt/google/earth/free
pst007x@pst007x-Serval-Professional:/opt/google/earth/free$ ./googleearth.bin
bash: ./googleearth.bin: No such file or directory
pst007x@pst007x-Serval-Professional:/opt/google/earth/free$
```

If I use Nautilus and navigate to "/opt/google/earth/free" "googleearth.bin" is there.

**ADDITIONAL:**

Tried creating a new profile and deleting my old profile, purging my system of Googleearth, used Janiter to remove all other references too, re-installed from fresh download, but same issue..

So how is it possible that a successful installation, with all the dependencies installed, and the googleearth.bin file there, confirmed, but will not launch, with the error "bash: ./googleearth.bin: No such file or directory"

Comment: Google earth should install itself into this path: '/opt/google/earth/free'. Please check if it is there and try to start 'googleearth' from that directory.

Comment: @Thomas "/opt/google/earth/free" the GOOGLEEARTH files are there, but do not run, when I launch in terminal I get the message file not found, but the file is there when I navigate to the folder. It's a strange one. Thanks

Comment: Please try this: `ldd /opt/google/earth/free/googleearth-bin`. But you are right - a strange one :)

Comment: Posted output above, thanks Any ideas? Appreciated..

Comment: bash: /opt/google/earth/free/googleearth-bin: No such file or directory

Comment: ... just a quick query - why are you downloading the deb package from google rather than installing & make from the repository version of google-earth?

Comment: seems fine - the missing libraries are located in /opt/google/earth/free - the googleearth-script takes care of this. A last try: `cd /opt/google/earth/free` and `./googleearth.bin`.

Comment: Thanks, I still get ... : bash: ./googleearth.bin: No such file or directory ... However the files are there. I have purged my system and re-installed, all successful...I must be missing something really simple :-/

Comment: @pst007x - what is the output of `ls -l /lib/ld*` - it should give three files all symlinked to the same underlying library.

Comment: Thanks, but pointless now... Unity failed, Lightdm failed, Nvidia driver failed, I've had to do a fresh install again. Does everyone have issues, causing constant fresh installs? Yes off topic I know.. Thanks for your help anyway... Posting this with my MAC... can you believe it! lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed...

I am using Ubuntu 64bit version and I was trying to logically install Google-Earth 64bit version... but there must be a bug in the installer..

So after a complete purge I installed the 32bit version and it worked!

Answer (score 8):

This is the method I used to install Google Earth on my 64bit Laptop and it worked perfectly

Firstly, I made sure I had all my media codecs installed then followed these instructions:

If you are running a 64-bit version of Ubuntu 12.04 then you will also need:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

To install Google Earth copy and paste the following command in the Terminal Window.

```
sudo apt-get install lsb-core
```

Google Earth 6.2  Latest Upgraded Version:

Download Google Earth 6.2 from [here](http://www.google.com/earth/download/ge/agree.html)

Select either: **32 bit .deb (For Debian/Ubuntu)** or **64 bit .deb (For Debian/Ubuntu)**

depending on your PC architecture and install in Software Center.

That's It

I dont see any mention in your question or subsequent answer about `ia32-libs`.  Have you installed this.  You need this for 64bit also.

Comment: I installed the 64bit version, however the ia32-libs is also installed and lsb-core. Thanks

Comment: Glad your sorted, if my answer resolved your issue, please accept it as the correct answer so others can benefit

Comment: Sorry dude, mis-understood... Still not working, I still get the message ... bash: ./googleearth.bin: No such file or directory ...Even though all the correct files are installed...  I am confused :-/

Comment: Version installed is: 6.2.2.6613-r0 .... still no joy.. Thanks

Comment: Have considered using Synaptic package package manager to uninstall it with all its dependencies then follow the instructions above to re-install, Maybe worth a shot

Comment: Yes, i tend to use Synaptic, but also tried Software Centre and GDebi installer. However, the installation is fine, always successful, but when I try to run, the file is not found. This is even using Terminal to launch, if I navigate using Nautilus to the folder the file is there but still will not launch 'file not found' when run... So I am confused.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had got very similar problem on Ubuntu 12.10 64bit. I successfully installed google-earth-stable_current_amd64.deb. But google-earth didn’t start. Just showed splash screen.
I tried terminal with error: Google Earth has caught signal 11
Main problem is your graphic card drivers only.
Also you must install ia32-libs,lsb-core packages. But this did not solve the problem with signal 11 crash.

I then installed AMD ATI drivers and this solved my problem.

My card:
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV770 [Radeon HD 4850]

Type the following in terminal for Radeon HD 2xxx, 3xxx a 4xxx :

- `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:makson96/fglrx`
- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get upgrade`
- `sudo apt-get install fglrx-legacy`
- `sudo reboot`

Answer (score 1):

install this first:

```
sudo apt-get install lsb-core msttcorefonts
```

then download the G.E. .deb file from google

then open the file in ubuntu sofware center and install..

it works fine on me.

Comment: Strange, that is what I have done. I always had it working fine on previous versions. It looks like a bug in my install. I really do not want to install again, it is a working laptop. Any ideas why terminal will say that the file is not found, but it is there and install was successful. An icon even appears in my launcher... At the moment I have used Win7 in a VM to run it, but not the best solution..