# Google earth - Unable to connect server

Tags: 12.04, google-earth

I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 and also installed Google Earth.  After opening Google earth instead of the maps only appears a black screen (I can see the menus with a lot of options in grey).  After waiting a few minutes, I see an error saying that google earth was unable to connect to the image server.

I used to have in the same computer Google Earth on ubuntu 10.10 without any problems.  Internet works fine, even I can use the internal browser of google earth.
I tried disabling ipv6, deleting ~/.config/google and everything I found in google, but it didn't work.  Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Is the whole screen a black screen or just the right window where the 3d view of the earth appears?

How did you install Google Earth? Did you download the original package and install the `libgl` package with `wget http://librarian.launchpad.net/7037027/libGL.so.1 -O libGL.so.1`?

If you are using 10.04, you can install Google Earth from the `mediabuntu` package, maybe this works. Otherwise, if you use 10.10, you can use [this guide](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2010/09/install-google-earth-ubuntu-10-10-maverick-meerkat/). This worked for me in 10.10 after I got crashes and black screens while using the original package. Using the original package was a mistake, because the original package never worked for me.

Comment: The black screen is only in the 3d view where the earth appears.  I use 12.04. I have installed "googleearth 6.0.3.2197+0.7.0-1".

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: I reinstalled GE folowing this instructions: http://tatobenavidez.blogspot.com.es/2012/06/como-instalar-google-earth-en-ubuntu.html

Comment: Does it work? I check the link out

Comment: It didn't work.  Just the same problem

Comment: I don't know if it will help, when I type "ldd /opt/google/earth/free/googleearth-bin" it displays "libgoogleearth_free.so => not found" and "libglobalnew.so => not found"

Answer (score 0):

I also show the following shared library dependencies missing after following Google's installation procedures on Ubuntu 12.04

```
test@localhost:~$ ldd /opt/google/earth/free/googleearth-bin |grep "not found"
libgoogleearth_free.so => not found
libglobalnew.so => not found
```

System Details:

```
uname -a
Linux test 3.2.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 7 16:16:45 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

It appears that both 'missing' dependencies are actually installed.

```
test@localhost:~$ locate libgoogleearth_free.so
/opt/google/earth/free/libgoogleearth_free.so

test@localhost:~$ locate libglobalnew.so
/opt/google/earth/free/libglobalnew.so
```

This apparent library dependency can be satisfied in Ubuntu 12.04 executing the following:

```
test@localhost:~$ sudo echo "/opt/google/earth/free/" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/google-earth.conf && ldconfig
```

Unfortunately, Google Earth still exhibits the same symptoms when launched.  (i.e. Black rendering area and seemingly unable to connect to the server with grayed menu options.)

It looks like this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130970/google-earth-will-not-launch) also discusses the issue:

Their solution of uninstalling the 64-bit version and subsequently installing the 32-bit version did not work.

Comment: I have solved the problem of the missing libraries, but it still doesn't work, black screen and no connection to the server.  My system is 32 bit (Linux bacterio-System-Product-Name 3.2.0-32-generic-pae #51-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 26 21:54:23 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux)

Comment: The above way of adding the libraries causes errors when runing other programs like skype or marble regarding Qt libraries.  I have solve this problem making links in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu.  I stil have the problem of the black screen and unable to connect server.